# Why would someone use pure CSS styled buttons over a bitmap/SpriteSheet technique?

Tags: css, css-sprites

We have an ongoing discussion at my job about the best way to deploy buttons over our websites. Some art directors ask for the buttons in pure CSS, I prefer to make Spritesheets in Photoshop. My argument- the kerning, text-effects like drop-shadow and aliasing all look better coming out of Photoshop. Their argument- you lose SEO points, translation engines can't change the buttons.

I'm sure there are arguments for both sides- am I missing something obvious for either of these arguments?

Comment: Also, CSS loading is faster than bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one, pure CSS buttons will certainly load faster, as they are only some very few lines of code. Many things can't be done in CSS/JS, those will have to be images, and will consume much bandwidth. But where you can save bandwidth, you should. This alone is a killer argument if speed is a priority for your project.

.

About effects looking better out of Photoshop... I wouldn't neccessarily agree here. I really don't think the browser implementations look bad in any way, so you would have to beat those, first.

.

Also, drawing a button image will likely cost more time than writing some lines of code. Same applies for changing the button. Maintainability is on CSS side ;)

.

I don't think the translation argument applies. If a "localization engine" can handle different CSS style/style classes/texts for different languages, it should be able to handle different images/sprites for different languages just as well.

.

About SEO: If you have a fallback text for a button or image (in case it cannot be loaded, IMO standard behaviour), that should apply to search engines as well as any string does. Though I'm not 100% sure here.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible argument for using pure CSS rather than images is *speed*.  Depending on how many buttons you have, it could take a considerable amount of time longer to load the images rather than CSS/plain-text.

Making things faster is always a big deal in software development.

Answer (score 1):

**1-** speed, css loads much faster than images

**2-** bandwidth, if you have 20 buttons trough all your website and 50000 unique users each day, it really makes an impact.

**3-** SEO boost, searchers prefer css to images, and of course above all text.

now, with images you can do things css cant (not for now at least).

It all depends on what you want to accomplish, the kind of website you want to make. The audience you focus on.

Look at Stackoverflow, it has little images. The rest is all pure css.

Answer (score 1):

Another point; Photoshop can't do cleartype (use sub-pixels), as it depends on the viewer's display specifications. So browser text looks much cleaner & sharper.

I prefer fully CSS based, simple buttons with light effects. If they really need a heavier look with more effects, then the way is make a button using bitmap backgrounds and HTML text, which preferably can be resized with CSS to cover variable text sizes.

Fully bitmapped buttons really look ugly especially in smaller text sizes, is a headache to maintain, duplicate, mass modifications (esp if you don't have the original PSD), takes much more bandwidth and load time, can't be typed using code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There may also be a performance issue. Put bluntly, more/larger images = more download. If you have many graphical elements, this will eventually slow down the site. On your broadband/fiber connection, this might not be such a huge problem, but it will be a problem on slower connections — especially if caching is disabled for some reason.

It will also take more time for the frontend developer to implement a spritemap solution than a pure CSS one.

Don't get me wrong, though. Spritemaps are brilliant, as they are much better performance-wise than multiple images, but CSS is simply faster to download, faster to develop, more flexible and better for structure.

In the end, it depends on the project. If it's about performance, development speed and money for the buck, then it's CSS all the way. If, however, the client demands that the site looks pixel perfect in his stone age browser, then you are better off using a spritemap.

Answer (score 0):

When you use graphics to display text on buttons, you can use CSS `text-indent: -100000;` with regular text - search engines will see it, but user won't.

```
<div class="button">Button text</div>
<style>
    .button {
        text-indent: -100000;
        background: url('path/to/image/with/button/text.jpg') no-repeat center center transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Sprites are good and fancy, but there's a real difference in (for example) 50kB image and 3kB of code, which does the same thing. If your site is visited hundreds per day, you will not see this difference, but when it could be billions....

Answer (score 0):

Besides loading faster (less requests), css buttons are easier to maintain. Need longer button, change text-color, disabled style, another set of colors. This is huge difference over time.

One disadvantage of css buttons is that for example text-shadow is not supported in some versions of IE - your buttons will not look exactly the same in every browser, but it will still lock decent if you code it correctyly.

Comment: Can't agree with you more (though I have a fancy Photoshop script to generate all my CSS and offsets for me).

Answer (score 0):

Their point is valid, but isn't the kerning and typography of Photoshop, MS Word and various DTP platforms always better than a browser-based solution? Consider how poorly browsers use fully-justified type - it's crap. By this same argument, would be abandon all CSS-based solutions because non-web tools can do a better job? The answer is NO or we'd all still be using Flash because it gives users a "better experience".

You have to consider the criticality of the user experience vs. ease of development and open standards. I believe that it is worth the effort to separate the content layer from the design layer as much as possible, and that means leaving behind images for curved corners, buttons and many other things that can now be rendered using CSS3. To do that we sometimes have to trade off a little bit of control and perfection to move forward with the available technology.

Comment: @Diodeus- thanks for your insight. I've looked at the results at the pixel level and Photoshop's anti-aliasing is definitely superior. I notice the difference, but perhaps it's not enough of a difference to warrant it.